# input tag required check gives tooltip : Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

If i add the required field to the input tag or use the email validation on the input tag in angularjs, I get a tooltip. I want to remove this. I am using bootstrap.

How do i do it?

Comment: Why -1. If it is so obv please provide ans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have you required field in a form, add the novalidate attribute to your form element. More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp)